# Knockout: How to pass the Checkbox "checked" value to a Click handler function?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, mvvm, knockout.js, data-binding

I want to send "true/false" value to a click handler, depending if the checkbox is checked or not.

- On check, it should send a 3rd parameter (isChecked) with value "true".
- On uncheck, it should send a 3rd parameter (isChecked) with value "false".

I'm sure this is really easy, but I'm having a hard time figuring it out. 
Here is the input element:

```
<input class="cards-view--item-checkbox pull-right" type="checkbox"
 data-bind="value: universalParcelId, checked: $parent.isChecked, checkedValue: true, 
 click: function(data, event, isChecked) { 
 return $root.addUPIDtoArray(data, event, $parent.isChecked()) }">
```

Click handler:

```
addUPIDtoArray: function (data, event, isChecked) {
    var self = this;

    self.isChecked = ko.observable();

    // If checked
    if(isChecked()) {
        self.upIDArray.push(data.universalParcelId);
        self.upIDWithIndexArray.push({
            universalParcelID: data.universalParcelId,
            searchResultIndex: data.searchResultIndex
        });

        // If unchecked
    } else if(!isChecked()) {
        // remove from array
    }

    return true; // allow the default "click" action, which is checking the box with a "check"
},
```

I thought i could use the "event" parameter, but for some reason it is coming through as a jQuery.event, instead of a regular DOM event. So I decided for the 3rd parameter. But it just doesn't work like this: gives error `$parent.isChecked is not a function`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you need to distinguish a click from some other way of setting the variable in the `checked` binding, you don't want a click handler. You just want to [`subscribe`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly-subscribing-to-observables) to the variable, which will execute your function whenever its value changes.

You've written your `click` binding as if adding the parameter to the parameter list will make Knockout know what to pass it. You'll want to re-think that. Generally, it's best to write your click handler as a member of your ViewModel and just make the binding like `click: methodName`.

Below is an example of a click binding on a checkbox. There's an interval toggling the checkbox each second. That won't trigger the click binding.

There is also a subscription that counts the times the value has changed, and what the last value was.

```js
vm = {
  box: ko.observable(true),
  changes: ko.observable(0),
  lastChange: ko.observable(''),
  stuff: ko.observableArray(),
    doThing: function() {
      vm.stuff.push(vm.box() ? 'checked' : 'not');
      return true;
    }
};

vm.box.subscribe(function(newValue) {
  vm.changes(vm.changes() + 1);
  vm.lastChange(newValue ? 'checked' : 'not');
});

ko.applyBindings(vm);

// This will change the checkbox without firing the click
setInterval(function() {
  vm.box(!vm.box());
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: box, click: doThing" />
<div>Changes: <span data-bind="text:changes"></span>, last:<span data-bind="text:lastChange"></span>
  <div data-bind="foreach:stuff">
    <div data-bind="text: $data"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you post a code example where you `subscribe` to the variable as you mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work by utilizing `$element.checked` and passing that as a parameter to my click handler function

```
<input style="display: none;"  class="cards-view--item-checkbox pull-right" type="checkbox"
data-bind="value: universalParcelId, checked: $parent.isChecked, click: function(data, event) { 
return $root.addUPIDtoArray($element.checked, data, event) }">
```

It might not be "best practice" but it works! What objections are there to doing it this way?